# Why is `data("kendoGrid")` undefined?

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have two Kendo grid definitions, in partial views, that are exactly the same save for the partial view model and the grid item model. Only one of then gives me the JavaScript console error 'Cannot read property 'dataSource' of undefined' on the line of code:

```
$("#index-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.bind("change", function (e) {...})
```

and the other does not. It is not `dataSource` that is undefined, but `$("#index-grid").data("kendoGrid")`. Yet, in the other identical grid, I do not get this error. Can the data provided to the data source perhaps invalidate the grid itself? The grid definitions look like this:

```
@model TerminalIndexModel
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@using ParkPay.Helm.ViewModels
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TerminalIndexItem>()
                .Name("index-grid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
                                columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsActive ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' />").Title("Active").Width(70);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.Remarks);
                                columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Destroy()).Width(80);
                            })
                .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                {
                    toolbar.Create();
                    toolbar.Save();
                })   
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 480px;"})                                                        
                .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                .Filterable()
                .Pageable()
                .Scrollable()
                .Sortable()
                .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                        .Ajax()
                                        .ServerOperation(false)
                                        .Batch(true)
                                        .PageSize(20)
                                        .Events(events => events.Error("kendoGridErrorHandler"))
                                        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                                        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Terminal"))
                                        .Update(update => update.Action("BatchUpdate", "Terminal"))
                                        .Create(create => create.Action("BatchCreate", "Terminal"))
                                        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("BatchDelete", "Terminal"))
                            )
)
```

with the only difference being `TerminalIndexItem` versus `LocationIndexItem' and and`TerminalIndexModel`versus`LocationIndexModel`, and of course the controller names in the CRUD definitions,`Terminal`versus`Location`. I am at my wit's end finding a difference between the two grids.

Comment: do both grids have a different name each?

Comment: No, they have the same name, in different folders.

Comment: Is there any difference in when the two grids get displayed in relation to when the problematic line executes? Meaning, is it possible that for the grid that works, it is already initialized when the line executes, and for the problematic grid it is not? Also, the grids with the same name aren't used on the same page at the same time, correct?

Comment: No, they are always used separately. It is possible what you say about the order though. I'll look into that, thanks. If it works you can make it an answer.

Comment: @G_P You are correct, and may make your comment an answer. Although some calls to `$("#index-grid").data("kendoGrid")` were contained within the jQuery `$( document ).ready()` function, the grid was not ready itself. I moved them into a handler for the grid `DataBound` event and all is good.

Comment: @ProfK glad it worked out for you - added answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any difference in when the two grids get displayed in relation to when the problematic line executes? Meaning, is it possible that for the grid that works, it is already initialized when the line executes, and for the problematic grid it is not?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue.

Weirdly, even though javascript code is launched after the page is loaded (using $(function() {...})), it seems the grid is not accessible from client yet.

**Solution :** You need to place your javascript code block after the grid initialization (@Html.Kendo.Grid(...)).

Answer (score 0):

The Name() of a Kendo UI HtmlHelper Extension is used as the `id` HTML attribute of its corresponding HTML element. The `id` attribute must be unique in the current page. If you render the same partial view twice both grids would end up with the same `id` attribute. As a result only the first grid will be initialized. Make sure that all HTML elements in your page have unique id. This can be done by appending some suffix to the Name():

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TerminalIndexItem>()
      .Name("index-grid" + ViewData["suffix"])
```

This suffix can be set in your action method which renders the partial view.

Comment: If both grids were on the same page I would definitely have given them different names.

Comment: Receiving this error means that $().data("kendoGrid") returns undefined because the grid failed to initialize for some reason. Check for JS errors or missing JS files.

Comment: It had not yet initialized, but did not fail to initialize. `$( document ).ready()` fires when the DOM is complete, but doesn't take intpo account the grid still has an AJAX 'read' pending to data bind.

Comment: @ProfK: I have the same issue. Would you know how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Sorry, @AjitGoel, I've stopped using Kendo years ago. It became way beyond my budget.