# Kendo controls don't seem to be ready in document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using the kendo `kendoNumericTextBox`.

The kendo js libraries are included *before* the following.

I am trying to store a reference to the actual input for later use like this:

```
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
        //Wire up the elemets with selectors
        $eventGrid = $("#jsGrid");
        $bedInput = $('#bed');
        $dateInput = $('#date');
        $operatingTimeInput = $("#operatingTime").data("kendoNumericTextBox"); <-- ERROR OCCURS HERE
        $plannedDowntimeInput = $("#plannedDowntime").data("kendoNumericTextBox");    

        fetchDayData(currentBed(), currentDate());
    })
```

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

However when stepping through, both `$operatingTimeInput` and `$plannedDowntimeInput` are undefined. If I later do these assigments manually in the console, everything works as expected.

Now, I seem to remember there being an event similar to `document.ready()` but specifically for kendo. Though, For the life of me, I can't find it...

Any thoughts?

**EDIT 1**

The fields are being initialized in a razor view like this:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox()
        .Name("operatingTime")
        .Max(24)
        .Min(0)
        .Step(0.05)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "operatingTime" })
    )
```

So as you can see, I have no control over *when* the textbox is actually "created". That's why I'm looking for a way to get the instance created *by the html helper*.

Comment: on which line does this error occur? How can we reproduce this? Where are `$operatingTimeInput` & `plannedDowntimeInput` defined? Are they in scope of the ready function or outside of it?

Comment: what do you mean razor template? Could you give us a reproducable example on github? There are just about a dozen unknowns to be any more then guessing right now

Answer (score 0):

One way which I tried to accomplish is like :

```
$(document)
.ready(function () {
   $("#operatingTime").ready(function(){
    setTimeOut(function(){
    if($("#operatingTime").data("kendoNumericTextBox")){
     //Wire up the elemets with selectors
    $eventGrid = $("#jsGrid");
    $bedInput = $('#bed');
    $dateInput = $('#date');
    $operatingTimeInput = $("#operatingTime").data("kendoNumericTextBox"); <-- ERROR WILL NOT OCCUR HERE
    $plannedDowntimeInput = $("#plannedDowntime").data("kendoNumericTextBox");    

    fetchDayData(currentBed(), currentDate());
      }
     },1000);
    });
    
})
```

Since I had comfort of waiting for 1 second, I went with this logic. let us know if something else has worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same problem today.

I solved it by moving my javascript that calls .data() to the bottom of the html document.

For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="kendo.custom.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    @* My kendoTextBox is here *@
    @*..... more content ... *@
    <script src="custom_script_that_calls_data.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think having the call to .data() lower on the page helps the kendo elements get fully initialized before the javascript is called.

Comment: I was inspired by a comment in this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49032909/16681055